# Usage of GET with request body with GraphQL

Tags: rest, graphql

I am using REST API GET with payload ( passing input params ) and it returns with JSON response.
I need to convert it into GraphQL, I have the schema and types defined,
but how to merge GET request payload along with GraphQL query JSON and process it to get the desired response back?

Example GET: http://localhost/myproject/getAllCustomers

payload :

```
{
    "name":"Harish"
    "passion":"reading"
}
```

GraphQL query :

```
{
  customer {
    name
    age
    city
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example?

Comment: For example : if I have an endpoint as http://localhost/getUser/id
I can write graphql query as below - 
type Query {
  users: [User]
  user(id: ID): User
}

BUT what if I have id as part of json in request body as payload and not as  part of url
How should I pass those params into graphql query ? is it the same way as above ?

Answer (score 0):

You pass `variable` to GraphQL `query` arguments

Query:

```
query getCustomer($name: String, $passion: String) {
  customer(name: $name, passion: $passion) {
    name
    age
    city
  }
}
```

Variable:

```
{
  "name": "Harish",
  "passion": "reading"
}
```